# x:bind and data validation for numeric field

Tags: validation, uwp, xbind

I'm struggling a bit with UWP, `x:Bind` and data validation.
I've got a very simple use case: I want the user to input an `int` in a `TextBox` and display the number in a `TextBlock` as soon as the user leaves the `TextBox`.
I can set the `InputScope="Number"` for the `TextBox`, but that doesn't prevent someone who type with a keyboard to type an alpha char (or paste something).
Problem is, when I bind a field with the `Mode=TwoWay`, it seems that you **can't** prevent a `System.ArgumentException` if the field that you bind is declared as `int`. I wanted to check in the `set` method if the input was a number, but the exception occurs just before that.
My (very simple) ViewModel (no model here, I tried to keep it as simple as possible):

```cs
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _MyFieldToValidate;
    public int MyFieldToValidate
    {
        get { return _MyFieldToValidate; }
        set
        {
            this.Set(ref this._MyFieldToValidate, value);
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisedPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected bool Set<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Equals(storage, value))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            storage = value;
            this.RaisedPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

My code behind:

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MyViewModel ViewModel { get; set; } = new MyViewModel() { MyFieldToValidate = 0 };

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And my whole XAML:

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="SimpleFieldValidation.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:SimpleFieldValidation"
    xmlns:vm="using:SimpleFieldValidation.ViewModel"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.MyFieldToValidate, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="inputText" InputScope="Number" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.MyFieldToValidate, Mode=OneWay}" x:Name="textToDisplay" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

If I type a numeric char in the `TextBox`, everything's OK. But if I type a non-numeric value (say "d") (it doesn't even reach the breakpoint at the first bracket of the `set` method for `MyFieldToValidate`):

[image: Imgur]

Is there a best practice to do what I want to do? The simplest solution would be preventing the user to type other char than numeric in the first place, but I've been searching for hours without finding a simple way... Another solution would be to validate the data on leaving the field, but I didn't find something relevant for UWP and `x:Bind` (few things for WPF thought, but they can't be replicated with a UWP).
Thanks!

Comment: just don't bind it to int, bind it to string property and you will do all necessary conversion via seters and getters (or use custom Converter and convert input to int manually)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @RTDev said, your exception is caused by the system can not convert string to int.

> You can create a class that allows you to convert the format of your data between the source and the target by inheriting from IValueConverter.
>
> You should always implement Convert(Object, TypeName, Object, String) with a functional implementation, but it's fairly common to implement ConvertBack(Object, TypeName, Object, String) so that it reports a not-implemented exception. You only need a ConvertBack(Object, TypeName, Object, String) method in your converter if you are using the converter for two-way bindings, or using XAML for serialization.

For more info, see [IValueConverter Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.IValueConverter).

For example:

```html
<Page.Resources>
    <local:IntFormatter x:Key="IntConverter" />
</Page.Resources>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.MyFieldToValidate, Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource IntConverter}}" x:Name="inputText" InputScope="Number" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.MyFieldToValidate, Mode=OneWay}" x:Name="textToDisplay" />
</Grid>
```

The IntFormatter class:

```cs
internal class IntFormatter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            return value.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        int n;
        bool isNumeric = int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out n);
        if (isNumeric)
        {
            return n;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your simple yet very useful answer. I looked at the converter but didn't try them yet. For my validation, I think I'll start another thread (later).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the users to type alphanumerical characters, I think the most elegant solution is to create a new class *NumberBox* that inherits from the class *InputBox* and overload the *OnKeyDown* method to intercept the alphanumerical keystrokes, something like this:

```
using Windows.System;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;

namespace MyProject.Controls
{
    public sealed class NumberBox : TextBox
    {
        protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key >= VirtualKey.Number0 && e.Key <= VirtualKey.Number9 ||
                e.Key >= VirtualKey.NumberPad0 && e.Key <= VirtualKey.NumberPad9 ||
                e.Key >= VirtualKey.Left && e.Key <= VirtualKey.Down ||
                e.Key == VirtualKey.Delete ||
                e.Key == VirtualKey.Tab ||
                e.Key == VirtualKey.Back ||
                e.Key == VirtualKey.Enter)
                base.OnKeyDown(e);
            else
                e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your XAML, add a namespace to reference the namespace where your *NumberBox* class is, and then replace *InputBox* with *control:NumberBox*, something like this:

```
<Page
    x:Class="MyProject.View.CalibrarEnfoque"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:MyProject.View"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:controls="using:MyProject.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <controls:NumberBox Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.MyValue, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```